# Buscar un registro en toda la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Me encuentro con la necesidad de dotar a mi web con la opción de recuperar todos los datos de un determinado proyecto, que pueden estar en diferentes tablas de la misma bd en #mysql.

La pregunta es como podría hacer una búsqueda, con codeigniter, en toda la bd similar a la que se puede hacer con phpmyadmin, por ejemplo?

Adjunto pantallazos para que se entienda mejor.
[image: Resultado de la búsqueda en todas las tablas]

[image: Consulta a todas las tablas]

Muchas gracias a todos/as por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Pero requieres nadamas de saber cuantas coincidencias encontró en cada tabla o que es lo que necesitas en si.

Comment: Fundamentalmente saber como sería la consulta para buscar en todas las tablas. Después ya decidiré si quiero solo las coincidencias o ver los registros. Llevo días con eso y no me acabo de aclarar con la sintaxis de la consulta, aunque si se puede hacer a través de phpmyadmin o Mysql Workbench. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es hacerlo con una consulta sql dinámica: utilizas una query para armar la query con la que obtendras el resultado deseado.

En este caso busco en information_schema los nombres de todas las tablas de un determinado schema y que contengan columnas del tipo vachar o text (tu puedes restringir de acuerdo a tu necesidad). Cada fila de esta query retorna una query con el nombre de la tabla, la columna y la cantidad de filas al buscar en dicha tabla y dicha columna una determina palabra (deberás reemplazar el signo de pregunta por la palabra buscada), cada fila además hace un `UNION ALL` con la siguiente fila, por lo que si copias el resultado de la query (todas las filas) y lo ejecutas obtendras la query deseada (deberás quitar el último `UNION ALL`).

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT("SELECT '", TABLE_NAME, "', '", COLUMN_NAME, "', count(*) FROM ",
    TABLE_NAME, ' WHERE ', COLUMN_NAME,  " LIKE '%?%' UNION ALL")

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'el_schema_donde_buscar' AND DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar', 'text');
```

Podrías modificar la query para que en lugar de que en cada fila busque en una tabla y una columna, busque en todas las columnas (varchar, text, etc) de la tabla.

El enfoque es el mismo que utilizo @eduardo-javier-maldonado, pero en lugar de utilizar php para crear la query dinámica yo uitlicé el lenguaje sql.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, lo que necesitas es obtener los nombres de todas tus tablas junto a sus columnas, esto puedes realizarlo manualmente creando un `array` o puedes obtenerlo por medio de una consulta.

Controlador:

```
public function index()
{
    $hola = $this->Cliente->obtener_todo('Boo');
    var_dump($hola);
    die();
}
```

Modelo:

```
public function obtener_todo($palabra)
{
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('table_name,column_name');
    $this->db->from('information_schema.columns');
    $this->db->where('table_schema','tu_base');
    $result = $this->db->get();

    if (!$result->num_rows() == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $result->result_array();
}
```

Ya que obtienes esos datos puedes hacer un recorrido en el `array` resultante y puedes buscar en todas esas columnas.

Modelo:

```
public function obtener_todo($palabra)
{
    $this->db->select('table_name,column_name');
    $this->db->from('information_schema.columns');
    $this->db->where('table_schema','tu_base');
    $result = $this->db->get();

    if (!$result->num_rows() == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    $dato = $this->buscar_en_todo($palabra, $result->result_array());
    return $dato;
}

public function buscar_en_todo($palabra, $arreglo)
{
    $datos = array();
    foreach ($arreglo as $item) {
        $this->db->select($item['column_name']);
        $this->db->from($item['table_name']);
        $this->db->like($item['column_name'], $palabra,'both');
        $result = $this->db->get();

        if(!empty($result->result_array())){
            $dato = $result->result_array();
            $dato['tabla'] = $item['table_name'];
            $dato['columna'] = $item['column_name'];
            $datos[] = $dato;
        }
    }
    return $datos;
}
```

Pasos:

1. Recibes la `palabra`.
2. Seleccionas el `nombre` de la `tabla` y de la `columna` (todos distintos).
3. Los obtienes del `information_schema`.
4. Siempre y cuando la `base de datos` sea igual a "tu base de datos".
5. Se manda la `palabra` y el `array` resultante a otra `función` para procesarla (se puede hacer en la misma función pero lo hice de esa manera para no hacerla muy larga).
6. Se declara un `arreglo` nuevo.
7. Se recorre el `arreglo` de las `tablas` y sus `columnas`.
8. Se selecciona la `columna` de la `tabla` siempre y cuando la `palabra` exista (el `both` es para que busque izquierda y derecha al usar el `like`).
9. Obtienes el resultado y lo pasas al arreglo que se creo en el punto `6` y ese mismo lo retornas fuera del ciclo.

Agregue el campo de `tabla` y `columna` nadamas para saber de donde trajo ese dato y listo.

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]